# I Want To Increment in Custom Attribute Every Time When Adding Div Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

here is my code.
when i alert variable Q it gives me correct output but after that it puts same value in multiple fields.
I want to change name attribute, like that 
first time its looks like 
name="program[1]"
2nd time it looks like
name="program[2]"
and so on.

```
var q = 0;
$('.admin').find('.level-saggg').each(function(){
   var Q = q+=1; 
   $('.admin').find('.level-saggg').removeAttr('name').attr('name','program['+Q+']');    
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `$('.admin').find('.level-saggg')` and also you don't have to remove the name `attribute` just change it.

```js
var q = 0;
$('.admin').find('.level-saggg').each(function(){
   q++;
   $(this).attr('name','program['+q+']');    
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var q = 1;
$('.admin').find('.level-saggg').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('name','program['+q+']');    
   q+=1;
})
```